# Aligning images horizontally inside a footer with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

right now I'm dealing with a problem in which images should be aligned horizontally to create a footer with bootstrap.

Unfortunately the partners div images stay pretty small and the elements in follow div are not horizontal, it happens they are in a vertical way.

Sample of the HTML:
`

```
<footer style="">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="img1.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 partner">
                <p>Partner </p>
                <ul class="row">
                    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="img2.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive position1" src="img3.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="img4.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive position2" src="img5.png" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 follow" style="">
                <p>Follow Us</p>

                <ul class="row">
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://awebsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="website.png" alt="Website"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

`

And this is the CSS used in footer:

```
    footer .logo{
margin-top: 15px;
}

li{
    display:block!important;
}

footer p{
    color: #928d93;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

footer ul li .position1{
    margin-top: 15px;
}

footer ul li .position2{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

footer .follow ul li{
    margin-left: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px){
    footer {
        text-align: center;
    }

    footer .logo{
        display: block;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }

    footer .partners{
        margin: 20px 0 40px;
    }

    footer .partners ul li{
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add a img of how it looks?

Comment: Add `col-md-4` in each of your child elements classes to fix the social media  to display horizontally and float as bootstrap intends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center item you can use flexbox:

```
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Some margin between partner li item:

```
.partner > ul > li {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Margin between follow li item:

```
footer .follow ul li {
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

Center partner li item in mobile view:

```
li > img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also since you used ul, by default ul have `padding-left: 40px` and `margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;`, you should remove those to really center ul/li items:

(REF: [Default CSS Values for HTML Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp))

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
footer .logo {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

footer p {
  color: #928d93;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

footer .follow ul li {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  footer {
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer .logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
  footer .partners {
    margin: 20px 0 40px;
  }
  footer .partners ul li {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}

.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.partner > ul > li {
  margin: 10px;
}

li > img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<footer style="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x50" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 partner">
      <p>Partner </p>
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 follow" style="">
      <p>Follow Us</p>
      <ul class="row centered">
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Facebook"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Instagram"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://awebsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Website"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly still had to do a few adjustments while positioning partners and follow. In the end now everything fits.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the vertical social media icon links, simply add `col-lg-4` to their class attribute and then add the different media screen you wish to apply when affected in browser, 
**ex:** `col-md-6` and/or `col-sm-12` and/or `col-xs-12`

```
<ul class="row">
     <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img class="col-md-4 img-responsive" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img class="col-md-4 img-responsive" src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a></li>
     <li><a href="http://awebsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="col-md-4 img-responsive" src="website.png" alt="Website"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Perhaps if you declare a height and width for your images, they may fit as you wish them to appear. I would suggest posting a bootply or fiddle with working images in your post. this may help to get a quicker and more accurate answer for your issue.
 [Something like this?](https://www.bootply.com/dtzGRCqUhO)

Comment: This solution gave me a something like a stair in social media images. Not really horizontal. 

I thought that because of the col-md-4 it would give me perfectly horizontal.

Comment: @Marcos Can you post a fiddle of your attempt perhaps?

Comment: @Marcos Nevermind Marcos, looks like you have your issue handled. ;) Good to see, best of luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

The flexbox really gave me everything centered although it needed the 4 items in to be in only one row.

So just had to adjust col to a bigger size.

In my scenario I had to give a margin-left of 2% in partners div.

```css
footer .logo {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

footer p {
  color: #928d93;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

footer .follow ul li {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  footer {
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer .logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
  footer .partners {
    margin: 20px 0 40px;
  }
  footer .partners ul li {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}

.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.partner > ul > li {
  margin: 10px;
}

li > img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<footer style="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x50" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 partner" style="margin-left:2%;">
      <p>Partner </p>
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 follow" style="">
      <p>Follow Us</p>
      <ul class="row centered">
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Facebook"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Instagram"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://awebsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Website"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```